# Python - Search through huge database

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, search

Good afternoon!
I have a really large csv file (11gb - couple million lines)
I have searched a lot but have not found a way to search through huge databases quickly, like if I search for a term it shows the row containing that term in the dataframe
Is there a way to do this through pandas/any other module

Comment: Can you specify more what you want to search?

Answer (score 2):

If I where you I would try what commentators above suggested, i.e. create a database to query your dataset in chunks:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

file = '/path/to/csv/file'

csv_database = create_engine('sqlite:///csv_database.db')
```

You'll need to iterate through your file and store the data into sqllite.

```
chunksize = 100000
i = 0
j = 1
for df in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=chunksize, iterator=True):
      df = df.rename(columns={c: c.replace(' ', '') for c in df.columns}) 
      df.index += j
      i+=1
      df.to_sql('table', csv_database, if_exists='append')
      j = df.index[-1] + 1
```

And then access your data by querying in in usual SQL:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT (columns) FROM table where (conditions)', csv_database)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you feel comfortable there is no nice way to do what you want. Maybe you can improve your speed search by storing your [csv in a DB](https://datatofish.com/import-csv-sql-server-python/), but have in mind that this is only worth if you are going to search many times in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

If the dataset fits system's memory, you can use string operators (especially `==` or [`contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)) for searching against a dataset.
Please see [Pandas comparison with SQL](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html) for some examples which demonstrate search Pandas functionality.